# Limited CheckBox in gridview

Tags: android, checkbox

How to set 5 limited for checkbox selection in grid view? I am using SparseBooleanArray...

```
holder.cb.setTag(position);
holder.cb.setContentDescription(Uri.withAppendedPath(
      MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID).toString());
holder.cb.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(),  isChecked);
    }
});
```

Comment: your question is not clear. Please describe some more.

Comment: how to limit checkbox selection in grid view?